# Excel Increment Letter Number Combinations

Tags: excel, increment

I was wondering if there was a formulation in excel to increment a combination of letters and numbers.

The structure is: AA1AA1, AA1AA2, etc and continues to AA1AB1, AA1AB2, and obviously cycles through (like number plates on a car) until it reaches ZZ0ZZ0.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with the output?  Seems it will produce 45,000,000+ permutaions.

Comment: Hi Ron, I'm wanting to sell unique id pet tags - and need it for the ordering. Need to keep an eye on which combination I'm up to for the next set of orders. Other cells will have what design they are etc. I dont need every output at once, but populating new tag groups will be achieved by dragging cells down to increment the ID.

Comment: It seems that the first serie should be AA0AA0 and the last ZZ9ZZ9, instead of AA1AA1 and ZZ0ZZ0, otherwise you'll not be able to keep the order if the series are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Ron that Excel is not the tool for generating such a large number of permutations, but just for the sake of fun... here's the formula you can try (paste it into cell `A2` and drag it down):

```
=RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,27+ROUNDDOWN(ROW(A1)/67600,0),4),1,MOD(ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/6759,0),10)),3)&RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,27+ROUNDDOWN(ROW(A1)/10,0),4),1,MOD(ROW(A1),10)),3)
```

The first transition from `AA1xxx` to `AA2xxx` happens in row 6761 (as expected: 10 numbers * (702 columns (ZZ) minus first 26 columns (A-Z)) = 6760 combinations.

Here are the results (ended on row `100000`):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. I know it's a big number and I'm not expecting to produce all results immediately. Perhaps in 1000 cell blocks. I'll test it and approve the comment as soon as I'm able.